# Coldfusion query returns no records when exact same query returns records in winSQL

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

There are two tables: u_case and schedule
There is a one to many relationship between u_case and schedule on u_case.cs_caseid = schedule.sd_caseid
Database is SqlServer

I need all of the records with 13 in u_case.cs_chapter
but do not have a "dline" in u_schedule.sd_class or "pln13" in schedule.sd_type.

This EXACT query works in WinSQL and returns 22 records.
The same EXACT query returns 2 records when using ColdFusion (verified with cfdump)

Are there any suggestions on why Coldfusion has a problem with this and how to fix it?  I have found a few queries with this problem.

```
SELECT a.cs_caseid, a.cs_case_number, a.cs_date_filed, a.cs_short_title, a.cs_office, a.cs_type
FROM u_case a
 WHERE a.cs_chapter = 13
 AND a.cs_date_term is null
 AND 0 = (
        select count(b.sd_caseid)
        from schedule b
        WHERE b.sd_caseid = a.cs_caseid
        AND b.sd_class = "dline"
        and b.sd_type = "pln13"
        )
```

I have this issue on three servers (2 CF10 and 1 CF9).  I also have other queries that this is happening to...often the CF query returns no records.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you connecting to the DB as the same user in both situations?

Comment: Something worth checking.  I will have to talk to the admin about that.  Thanks for a direction to look

Comment: I wonder if it's some vagary of your usage of (non-standard) double quotes, not single quotes on your hard-coded data values?

Comment: Yes, just checked.  Both are using the same userid

Comment: I have tried it both ways.  I started with single quote.  Just to be sure, I just changed it back to single quotes. No help.  As a separate test, I use <cfqueryparam.... > and set them to those literals.  That didn't help either.

Comment: I would be willing to try a JOIN, but I don't see how I can use that here (I don't have a lot of practice in joins)

Comment: Get your admin to run a trace whilst you call the query from CF, and see what JDBC is actually passing to the DB. That might shed some light on proceedings

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, Adam.  I am going to get with my admin in the morning.  My GUESS, now that I've played with this for a coupld of days, is that there is some security built into the table that is being handled differently when ColdFusion runs it.

Comment: Are you certain you are using the same exact query? In your description you stated `do not have a "dline" in u_schedule.sd_class OR "pln13" in schedule.sd_type`, yet in your query you have `b.sd_class = "dline" AND b.sd_type = "pln13"` This query may not give you results that match what you described because of the AND in the query.

Comment: (Edit)  I think he just meant he wants to exclude matching records that have those values, not that it was excluded from the SQL. Ed - Nothing to do with your question, but ... yes, you could rewrite the above as an OUTER JOIN. However, given the one-to-many relationship, and the fact that the query does not return any data from the schedule table, using WHERE NOT EXISTS (...) would be more appropriate than count. It may also be more efficient. Though actual results depend on a number of factors (indexes, optimizer, etcetera). Examine the execution plan for a definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if CF is just having trouble parsing the strange-ish SQL format you have there? Try this:

```
SELECT a.cs_caseid, a.cs_case_number, a.cs_date_filed, a.cs_short_title, a.cs_office, a.cs_type
FROM u_case a
WHERE a.cs_chapter = 13
AND a.cs_date_term is null
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM schedule b
    WHERE b.sd_caseid = a.cs_caseid
    AND b.sd_class = "dline"
    AND b.sd_type = "pln13"
)
```